# Excel ODBC Connection Issues and HY000 CURLError

Tags: odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to connect Excel to our Snowflake instance so that users can pull data into Snowflake. I've installed the latest ODBC driver and set the User and Server as required.  The authenticator is set to externalbrowser.  When we attempt to use that connection within Excel, one of two things occurs:

1. A bunch of browser tabs open but the user is able to connect and bring in data. Not sure why we have multiple tabs but at least they get what they need.
2. The connection just spins, and ultimately we end up with a HY000 error saying that the REST Request for our URL failed; code=52 msg=Server returned nothing (no headers, no data), oS code=2, osMsg='No such file or directory'.

We have tried multiple options and all of our other connections (JDBC for example) works just fine with the external browser setting. There doesn't seem to be much of a difference between users that can connect and those that can't.

Comment: Please collect the ODBC logs and post it for review. Steps for getting the logs are detailed here: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors

Comment: I was able to collect the logs & tried a few things.  We have authenticator set to externalbrowser & when I downloaded the new driver, I was able to get it to work for a bit. After awhile, it stopped working and when we set to connect, the browser never opened. Tried closing all browsers, etc.. and nothing seemed to work. Ran the ODBC test and SnowCD and it showed a connection and the JDBC connectors worked fine.  I think tried changing the allow_id_token=false (which it already was set to) and it suddenly started to pop open the browser again & connected. However, it was already set to False.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good Knowledge Base article written about connecting to Snowflake from Excel.

Skip Step 1: Configure SSO with Azure AD if you are not using SSO. Go on to Step 2 onward.

This is the article: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/HOW-TO-connect-to-Snowflake-authenticating-with-Azure-AD-SSO-from-MS-Excel-ODBC-driver

Comment: I tried those settings as well as the registry changes and getting the following:

Details: "ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Snowflake][Snowflake] (4) 
      REST request for URL https://companyname-dwh.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/authenticator-request failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=52 msg='Server returned nothing (no headers, no data)' osCode=2 osMsg='No such file or directory'.